# TightVNC: How to list all connected users

Tags: security, logging, connection, surveillance, tightvnc

I'm using TightVNC (Version 2.8.5) to connect to machines.
While using it the clipboard between my Computer and the remote Computer is transfered in both directions. I need that function, so it's ok for me.
Today I noticed that the clipboard changed (likely because another user also connected via TightVNC).
I didn't find a possibility to find out who connected or watched me - that's worrying me...

**How can I find out which other users**

- are currently connected via TightVNC?
- were connected in the past? (Logfile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows you can find at least from what IP another connection is established.
On tightVNC server launch command prompt and try:

netstat -an | find "ESTABLISHED" | find ":5900"

Answer (score 0):

Get all current VNC Connections to your Computer including the hostname:

```
C:\>FOR /f "tokens=3*delims= " %a IN ('netstat -n^|find "5900"') DO @FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %d IN ('echo %a^|find /v "5900"') DO @for /f "tokens=3delims= " %e in ('tracert -h 1 %d ^| find "max"') do @echo VNC connection from %e (%d) [%b]
```

Get all current VNC Connections from your Computer including the hostname:

```
FOR /f "tokens=3*delims= " %a IN ('netstat -n^|find "5900"') DO @FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %d IN ('echo %a^|find "5900"') DO @for /f "tokens=3delims= " %e in ('tracert -h 1 %d ^| find "max"') do @echo VNC connection to %e (%d) [%b]
```

And here is a batch file `ShowVncConnections.bat` for that purpose:

```
@echo off
FOR /f %%a in ('hostname') DO set hostname=%%a
FOR /f "tokens=3*delims= " %%a IN ('netstat -n^|find "5900"') DO @FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%d IN ('echo %%a^|find "5900"') DO @for /f "tokens=3delims= " %%e in ('tracert -h 1 %%d ^| find "max"') do @echo VNC connection from %hostname% to %%e (%%d) [%%b]
FOR /f "tokens=3*delims= " %%a IN ('netstat -n^|find "5900"') DO @FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%d IN ('echo %%a^|find /v "5900"') DO @for /f "tokens=3delims= " %%e in ('tracert -h 1 %%d ^| find "max"') do @echo VNC connection from %%e (%%d) to %hostname% [%%b]
pause
```

Produced Output:

> VNC connection from MyComputer to AIP00000298 (172.20.17.55) [ESTABLISHED]
>   VNC connection from MyComputer to BMABN0014.aip.dagherp.local (172.20.17.67) [WAITING]
>   VNC connection from BMABN3145 (172.20.18.5) to MyComputer [ESTABLISHED]